# jQuery Slide Menu Function

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a simple jQuery menu for some references.  Essentially, I want the user to click on a 'Term' and the definition of that term is toggled to slide up to hide or slide down to be viewed.

Here is my code for the jQuery (still very new to this!)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("p").hide();


$("h3").click(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle("slow");
     });


});
</script>
```

It works fine! However, I can't figure out what I need to do to make it a 'singular instance.'  Right now (obvious given the selector), if the person clicks on any heading, it will toggle all the paragraph elements at the same time.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please post your HTML and indicate which tags you want to animate.

Comment: When you use the name of the tag as a selector, all of the elements with this tag will be selected. There are selectors for elements with specific id $("#element") or specific class names $(".classname"), specific tags $("tag") etc. Look at the list of selectors from w3schools website at:  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

I believe instead of $('p').slideToggle('slow'), you use

```
$(this).children('p').slideToggle('slow')
```

Assuming that p is a child the h3, if not you have to use selectors to get there. But $(this) will give you what you clicked on.